# rewrite postgresql query to use with mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, activerecord

I have a postgresql query in my Ruby on Rails application, which I have to rewrite to use it with mysql. And I don't understand how to do it, I always have an error and I think it is something concerning timestamps.
Here is the query:

```
includes(:mass_scan_list)
    .where("mass_scan_lists.enabled = ?", true)
    .order("mass_scan_lists.urgent DESC,
            CASE mass_scan_lists.urgent WHEN true THEN extract(epoch from mass_scan_tasks.updated_at) ELSE -extract(epoch from mass_scan_tasks.updated_at) END")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `extract(epoch from mass_scan_tasks.updated_at)` with `unix_timestamp(mass_scan_tasks.updated_at)`